# Color cells of a table

Tags: javascript, plotly

How can I conditionally set color to the cells of a table? I would like to set green if the cell value is less than a certain number, red otherwise (for example).

```
var data = [{
    type: 'table',
    header: {
        values: fore_draft_lst_show,
        align: "center",
        line: {
            width: 1,
            color: 'black'
        },
        fill: {
            color: "grey"
        },
        font: {
            family: "Arial",
            size: 12,
            color: "white"
        }
    },
    cells: {
        values: values,
        align: "center",
        line: {
            color: "black",
            width: 1
        },
        font: {
            family: "Arial",
            size: 11,
            color: ["black"]
        },
        fill: {
            color: [
                'rgba(140,124,66,1)',
                cellColorArray
            ] // cellColorArray = ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)',...]
        }
    }
}];
```

Here, cellColorArray is an array containing rgba values for each cell. However, when I run this code, it sets colors for entire rows and not individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using the line not the cell.

Why not do something simple (here in php)

```
<?php switch ($myvalue)
{ case 100: $style = "add you style commands eg font-color:red and so on":} ?>
<td style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
```

Comment: Plotly table cell coloring method in javascript,not in php.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this doc atleast if it helps you [read](https://community.plot.ly/t/set-individual-colors-based-on-value-of-cell-in-plotly-table/6943)